# Show Non matching values query of two columns

Tags: sql-server

Tried this Query:

```
    SELECT     Movements.[date of movement], 
               Movements.[Date of value], 
               Movements.Description 
    FROM       Movements 
    INNER JOIN Documents 
    on         Movements.Description<> '%' + Documents.Costumer+ '%'  
    AND        Documents.[Value with IVA] <> Movements.Value 
    Group by   Movements.[date of Movement], 
               Movements.[Date of value], 
               Movements.Description, 
               Documents.Costumer, 
               Documents.[Value with IVA]
```

The problem is that He shows me all Costumers that doesnt match with the the description... And what I want is the descriptions that do not match one single time....
 I want to me to show me like:

```
Date of movement    Date of Value    Description
12-12-2011           1-12-2011       123123
12-12-2011           12-12-2011      121121
13-12-2011           13-12-2011      121121
```

What it shows me is this

```
Date of movement    Date of Value    Description
  12-12-2011           1-12-2011       123123
  12-12-2011           12-12-2011      121121
  13-12-2011           13-12-2011      121121
  12-12-2011           1-12-2011       123123
  12-12-2011           12-12-2011      121121
  13-12-2011           13-12-2011      121121
  12-12-2011           1-12-2011       123123
  12-12-2011           12-12-2011      121121
  13-12-2011           13-12-2011      121121
```

Comment: what is the logic here ? try removing last 2 lines from the `GROUP BY`

Comment: Nice it worked! Thanks everyone that helped me

Comment: @Squirrel Can I do it by showing the Documents.[Value with IVA] too? Cause I just need to not show the costumer name... But the thing is when I put the Value in IVA in group by it shows me all the lines

Comment: @Squirrel the query that Im using    SELECT     Movements.[date of movement], 
               Movements.[Date of value], 
               Movements.Description 
    FROM       Movements 
    INNER JOIN Documents 
    on         Movements.Description<> '%' + Documents.Costumer+ '%'  
    AND        Documents.[Value with IVA] <> Movements.Value 
    Group by   Movements.[date of Movement], 
               Movements.[Date of value], 
               Movements.Description

Comment: Note that there might be multiple `[Value with IVA]`, for each combination of ` [date of Movement], [Date of value], Description`. you can use aggregate function like `min()` or `max()` to show only one of the value.

Comment: @Squirrel, I have 653 in total in my table, and 3 of them matches so it should show just 650, doing the first thing that you said, "removing last 2 lines from the `GROUP BY`", it gives me the 650 rows like it was suppost to give, but when adding `[Value with IVA]` it gives me the 3 lines back... ALL this to ask if you could put one example in answer? cause I think I didn't get it|

Comment: @Squirrel I got it But thanks! Really Helpfull

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to use the [`LIKE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) operator instead of `<>`:

```
on Movements.Description not like '%' + Documents.Costumer + '%'
```

or is it the other way:

```
on Documents.Costumer not like '%' + Movements.Description + '%'
```

Comment: Didn't change... I'm still getting more than 1 time the same description

Answer (score 0):

Insted of this:

```
 SELECT     Movements.[date of movement], 
           Movements.[Date of value], 
           Movements.Description 
FROM       Movements 
INNER JOIN Documents 
on         Movements.Description<> '%' + Documents.Costumer+ '%'  
AND        Documents.[Value with IVA] <> Movements.Value 
Group by   Movements.[date of Movement], 
           Movements.[Date of value], 
           Movements.Description, 
           Documents.Costumer, 
           Documents.[Value with IVA]
```

Do this:

```
 SELECT     Movements.[date of movement], 
           Movements.[Date of value], 
           Movements.Description 
FROM       Movements 
INNER JOIN Documents 
on         Movements.Description<> '%' + Documents.Costumer+ '%'  
AND        Documents.[Value with IVA] <> Movements.Value 
Group by   Movements.[date of Movement], 
           Movements.[Date of value], 
           Movements.Description
```

ps: all Credits go to @Squirrel